Every time I open vscode from the vscode icon, it defaults to opening a C file
When I open vscode from the vscode desktop icon, it always opens a C file, which is too annoying. What should I do to display the default welcome interface or an empty interface of vscode every time I open it?
When I modified the "workbench. startupEditor" option in the settings file to "welcome page", it still did not change, and every time I opened it, the C file still appeared

Are you using Windows?

I wager this is just due to hot exit. what if you close that file and then close and reopen?

Does this answer your question? How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?

Thank you very much for your answers. I have resolved this issue through partial answers. I clicked on the properties of the Vscore icon on the desktop and saw that the "target" content was "D: \ Microsoft VS Code \ Code. exe" and "D: \ Code \ C". I deleted "D: \ Code \ C" and also removed the "notes" content to solve this problem. This may be due to the initial configuration of C language

I will assume you are using Windows. (This advice holds similar on other operating systems, but the mechanics will vary.)
Fix the shortcut
On your desktop shortcut icon, right click and select “Properties”. Click on the “Shortcut” tab. The “Target” text box describes the command-line used to launch VSCode.
Next, take a look at the VSCode command-line options. These tell VSCode how to start up. The one of interest is the --profile option.
If your shortcut’s Target has a profile, remove it. (Remove both the --profile text and the double-quoted text that immediately follows it.)
Fix your settings
Next you will want to take some time to read through the User and Workspace Settings.
If you can’t figure out how to fix it and don’t mind starting everything from scratch, just find and delete the “settings.json” file content. (Doing this is described in the “Common Questions” section of that page.)
Default settings
If that doesn’t work, you can look through your default settings and see if something is wrong with that. This seems to me to be unlikely, though, because either you (or an install agent) has to have had specifically modified that to be different from the VSCode defaults.
Other OSes
Alas, I have never used VSCode, but these kinds of steps are common for basically any editor software. If you are on Linux using GNOME, for example, you will have to mess with the vscode.desktop file to check to make sure there is no profile set, and everything else works the same.
